# JS file in root not loading in Google Appengine

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, yaml, service-worker

I am adding a service worker in Google Appengine. According to the documentation, `sw.js` must be in the same folder as the HTML file which is calling it.

I added the following to my `app.yaml` file, but I am still getting **404 Not Found** for the `sw.js` file:

```
- url: /(index|sw)\.js$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (index|sw)\.js$
  application_readable: true
```

I tested my regular expression in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), so I know that's correct.

I think there's something wrong with the rest of the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex omits the extension from the `static_files` file.  Try:

```
- url: /(index|sw)\.js$
  static_files: \1.js
  upload: (index|sw)\.js
  application_readable: true
```